# Set Proxy for Vitamio Player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, playback

i want to play mms stream so i m using Vitamio Player. On open network it plays well. But on proxy gives error. So how do i set proxy for it.. i tried

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my proxy host name");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

but doesnt seem to work for either vitamio player, nor android media player. I am targeting `Android 4.2`. Is there still no provision for setting proxy in the `Android Media PLayer`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the global proxy is set in `ConnectivityService.java` through `setGlobalProxy` as shown in http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#3054 . I am not sure if there is any system property to set the global proxy.

Comment: hey.. thanks for replying.. actually i m targetting 4.2 but need to support since 4.0 .. Settings.Global is available since 4.2.. so need something since 4.0.